# auto fill otp web view react native android

Tags: android, react-native, webview, autofill

Have anyone worked with webview in react native for auto-filling otp from phone - android? It is working fine with iOS with a great facility for one-time-code but android web view isnt working. Any idea on this ?

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide a GitHub link with sample code, so that we can better analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

you can write javascript code which doses by selecting the input box insert OTP read by react native and inject this javascript code t webview